# Casablanca C++ rest throws error "generic:1" on MAC

Tags: macos, rest, casablanca

I am using cpprest 2.6.0 (also tried with 2.5.0) on OSX 10.10 and 10.11.

While doing a Post I randomly get error "Error resolving address" generic:1". This happens once in 1000 calls.

Seems to be coming from start_request in http/client/http_client_asio.cpp

Anyone else seeing this?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar issue with Android ... getting the same error with a simple GET .... Error resolving address is the message